# Can I install rsyslog and syslog on the same machine

Tags: linux, logging, centos5, syslog, rsyslog

I'm running CentOS 5 with syslog already installed. When I try to install rsyslog I receive the message

```
file /etc/logrotate.d/syslog from install of rsyslog-7.6.7-1.el5.centos.x86_64 
conflicts with file from package sysklogd-1.4.1-44.el5.x86_64
```

After looking around a bit it doesn't appear that they can be installed on the same machine, but I'd like to be 100% sure.

Comment: I have heard of machines having both installed, never done it myself. If they are both running it requires some special configuration, as expected. Is syslogd package running while you try to install rsyslog?

Comment: Just a note: CentOS 5 is EOL as of earlier this year.

Comment: @cteneyck it was but I got the same result when I tried to run it while syslog was stopped